# In Adobe Photoshop drop shadow angle shadow

Tags: adobe, photoshop, layer, shadow, angle

**I have problem with drop shadow for specific layer with angle shadow if I changed for one layer it's change for all layers[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBj82.png)!! why??**

Answer (score 0):

You either have all the layers selected or have "Auto Select" checked. Or one of the layers is nested in another layer forming a group.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure only 1 layer is selected. Try making a new layer and applying it.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to to this :

1. select which Layer you want to work on
2. right click on the Layer
3. click on Blending Option
4. choose Drop Shadow from menu

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have global light selected.

If you change the shadow effects on an element with global light selected, ALL other images with global light checked, regardless of what layer they are on, will change also.

If you want to change the shadow of a single object, be sure global light is not selected.

[image: photoshop styles dialog box]